# In R how do I pair XML node values from common parent nodes?

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I have following example XML:

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <span class="title">Color</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column property">Blue</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <span class="title">Shape</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column property">Square</div>
  </div> 
</body>
```

How could I use R to pair each title to their property and output:

```
Color = Blue
Shape = Square
```

I tried following script, but the title has XML tags around and property is missing:

```
library(XML)

getDetails <- function(id) {
  html <- htmlTreeParse( "exampleXML.html" ,useInternal = TRUE)
  xpathSApply( html , "//div[@class='row']" , function(row) { 
    print( xmlElementsByTagName(row, "span", recursive = TRUE) )
  })
}

getDetails()
```

Also no luck with:

```
library(XML)      #to install use: install.packages("XML")
library(xml2)     #to install use: install.packages("xml2")
library(magrittr) #to install use: install.packages("magrittr")

extract_info <- function(x){
   title <- x %>% xml_find_first(".//span[@class='title']") %>% xml_text
   property <- x %>% xml_find_first(".//div[@class='column property']") %>% xml_text
   setNames(property, title)
 }

html <- htmlTreeParse( "exampleXML.html" ,useInternal = TRUE)
html %>% xml_find_all("//div[@class='row']") %>% extract_info
```

> Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
>         no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "c('HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a nested `xpathSApply()` where outer loop iterates across *rows* to parse corresponding values of each row's *title* and *property*:

```
library(XML)

example_html <- paste0('<body>',
                   '  <div class="row">',
                   '    <div class="column">',
                   '       <span class="title">Color</span>',
                   '    </div>',
                   '    <div class="column property">Blue</div>',
                   '  </div>',
                   '  <div class="row">',
                   '    <div class="column">',
                   '       <span class="title">Shape</span>',
                   '    </div>',
                   '    <div class="column property">Square</div>',
                   '  </div>', 
                   '</body>')

doc <- htmlTreeParse(example_html, useInternal = TRUE)

columns <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class='row']", function(row){
   title <- xpathSApply(row, "div[@class='column']/span", xmlValue)
   property <- xpathSApply(row, "div[@class='column property']", xmlValue)
   setNames(gsub(" ", "", property), gsub(" ", "", title))    # GSUB TO STRIP WHITESPACE
})

columns <- setNames(property, title)
columns
#  Color    Shape 
#  "Blue" "Square"
```

Alternatively, assuming strict consistency in *rows* without missing child elements or multiple same named elements for *title* and *property* values, consider a couple of `xpathSApply()` calls:

```
title <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class='column']/span", xmlValue)
property <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class='column property']", xmlValue)

columns <- setNames(property, title)
columns
#   Color    Shape 
#  "Blue" "Square"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `xml2` you can do the following:

```
library(xml2)     #to install use: install.packages("xml2")
library(magrittr) #to install use: install.packages("magrittr")

extract_info <- function(x){
  title <- x %>% xml_find_first(".//span[@class='title']") %>% xml_text
  property <- x %>% xml_find_first(".//div[@class='column property']") %>% xml_text
  setNames(property, title)
}

html <- read_xml( "exampleXML.html" )
html %>% xml_find_all("//div[@class='row']") %>% extract_info
```

Which gives you the following named vector:

```
   Color    Shape 
  "Blue" "Square"
```

Comment: I got `Error: could not find function "%>%"`. I tried to install the package from RStudio > Tools > Install Packages... > xml2. Also added `library(xml2)` to the beginning of the script. No luck.

Comment: I added "Also no luck with:" section to my question. Can you have a look at it and possibly update your answer please?

Comment: You figured it out your self. Sorry for the half-complete answer. The trick is to read the file via `read_xml` and (unlike `rvest` a more convenient wrapper around `xml2`) `xml2` does not import `magrittr::%>%` be default.

Answer (score 1):

If your XML is well-formed (i.e. the order of elements doesn't change) then you can do:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

doc <- read_xml(txt)

vals <- xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, ".//*[@class='title' or @class='column property']"))
map_chr(seq(1, length(vals), by=2), ~sprintf("%s = %s", vals[.], vals[.+1])) %>% 
  cat(sep="\n")
```

as well.